# Viewing two areas of a file with different folding side by side

Tags: org-mode

In org-mode is there a way to view two areas of the same file in two frames/windows side by side such that folding and unfolding in the left frame/window is NOT reflected in the right frame/window?

Comment: See [Narrow Indirect](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NarrowIndirect).

Answer (score 6):

You could use indirect buffers. M-x clone-indirect-buffer will give you a new indirect buffer next to your main buffer. You can find more info here https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Indirect-Buffers.html

Comment: Any way to create a new indirect buffer as a vertical split?

Comment: I don't know how to do it directly but I usually do something like this. Create the indirect buffer; Close that window (C-x 1); Start a vertical split with (C-x 3); Change buffer in that window to the indirect buffer with (C-x b).